# How were Memory Cards connected to the Original Xbox?

Tags: xbox

I just saw a video showing every single Memory Card since the Neo Geo and I learned that the Original Xbox also had memory cards but this video didn't showed where or how they were connected to the main system.

How were memory cards connected to the Original Xbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the original XBOX was the first console to use on-board storage, memory cards were capable of being used in the same manner as consoles like the Nintendo 64 and Dreamcast; by inserting the memory card into the controller (*note the top slot on the screenshot below*).

[image: Xbox controller should screenshot.]

The video below demonstrates this:

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also, what's up with that controller? Is that a USB port mod in the second memory card slot? (the port closer to the cable)

Comment: @Lemon yes, the controller in the picture has been modified to support USB.